# I can not install Laravel 5.4 with composer

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I am trying to install `Laravel 5.4` with composer using composer. I get the following message.

Here's a screenshot

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: You need a PHP extension `ext-mbstring`, enable it in your php.ini and you should be good to go

Comment: I am surprized multi byte string (mbstring) is not enabled/installed by default... Dis you install XAMPP?

Comment: It says you are missing the `mbstring` extension. Try installing the `php-mbstring` extension.

Comment: mbstring was commented. I uncomment it and now ok.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file `php.ini` on Notepad or any other text editor.
Look or find this

```
;extension=php_mbstring.dll
```

to enable remove the semicolon `;`